# C++ the meaning of getting size of a array

Tags: c++, arrays

Here is a macro for getting array size

```
#define array_size(array) \
(sizeof( array ) / (sizeof( array[0] ) * (sizeof( array ) != sizeof(void*) || sizeof( array[0] ) <= sizeof(void*)))
```

I think normally (sizeof( array ) / (sizeof( array[0] )) is good enough to get the size of the array.

I guess the part

```
(sizeof( array[0] ) * (sizeof( array ) != sizeof(void*) || sizeof( array[0] ) <= sizeof(void*))
```

is to avoid the whole thing divided by zero, anyone could help to explain?

Thanks in advance.

Cheers,

Comment: I would guess that this is to prevent accidental abuse with a decayed pointer-to-first-element. In that case, and platform-dependently, this would have value `0`...

Comment: sizeof can never return zero.

Comment: "is to avoid the whole thing divided by zero" On the contrary, it is to force a divide-by-zero at compile time when `sizeof array == sizeof(void*)` and `sizeof array[0] > sizeof(void*)`.

Comment: @DanielFischer : Is that so that `struct Foo {int i,j;}; Foo *f; int s = array_size(f);` is flagged as a compile-time error?

Comment: This is part of the "modern" approach to programming that assumes most programmers cannot write correct code, so real programmers must write convoluted, unreadable code in order to protect lesser beings (including themselves) from their frailties.

Comment: `sizeof( array ) != sizeof(void*)` is this a rare case?

Comment: @Roddy Possibly. But `sizeof(struct Foo) == sizeof(void*)` is common on 64-bit platforms, so that wouldn't be caught. But in principle, yes, it's to detect pointers instead of arrays.

Comment: @DanielFischer - looks like it has more holes than a string vest. Is it a recommended practice, or just lulling you into a false sense of security...?

Comment: @Daniel I feel a bit confuse :0. if    sizeof(array)==sizeof(void*), on windows 8, (void*) is 4 bytes. The means the size of the array is 4 bytes. The how comes the size of the first element of the array larger than    sizeof(void*)?

Comment: Using this kind of stuff in C++ is just bad. Don't do it. Replace the array with std::vector if you need to query its size.

Comment: @user2185248 If `array` is in fact a pointer, and not an array, it can point to a type larger than `void*`. Then you get `sizeof array / 0` and a compilation error.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Multiplying `sizeof array[0]` in the divisor by

```
(sizeof( array ) != sizeof(void*) || sizeof( array[0] ) <= sizeof(void*))
```

makes the divisor zero if

```
sizeof array == sizeof(void*)
```

*and*

```
sizeof array[0] > sizeof(void*)
```

In those cases, you get a division by zero during the compilation, which would cause the compilation to fail.

These checks are an attempt to detect arguments that are pointers (be they the result of array-to-pointer conversion or not), since one can't know how large an "array" a pointer points to by using that quotient.

It fails if other pointer types have different sizes than `void*`, and it doesn't detect pointers to things that are not larger than `void*`s. It probably does more harm than good by lulling the author in a false sense of security.

Comment: And of course having an array of pointer is perfectly legal and this macro will fail on it...

Answer (score 6):

> I think normally (sizeof( array ) / (sizeof( array[0] )) is good enough to get the size of the array.

Although it is not your primary question, but you mentioned it. The correct way to determine array size in C++ is using templates:

```
template<typename T, size_t size>
constexpr size_t array_size(T(&)[size]){
    return size;
}
```

Comment: Additional bonus: much clearer error message when the argument is not an array. It should be `constexpr`, though.

Comment: Yes, ideally it should be `constexpr`. Unfortunately many compilers in use today does not support it, therefore I omitted it.

Answer (score 1):

I assume this part is clear: `sizeof( array ) / sizeof( array[0] )`

This part `(sizeof( array ) != sizeof(void*) || sizeof( array[0] ) <= sizeof(void*))` is a logical expression, so yielding true or false. When computing the whole expression, so multiplying `sizeof( array[0] )` with the logical expression, the compiler converts the logical expression to 0 or 1. So you end up with
`sizeof( array ) / (sizeof( array[0] ) * 1)` or
`sizeof( array ) / (sizeof( array[0] ) * 0)`.

The first case is the normal and desired case. The second case will give you a compiler error because of division by zero. So the code will not compile if you call for example:

```
long *p; // assuming a platform with sizeof(long)==sizeof(void*)
array_size(p);
```

But it will not catch errors like:

```
char *p;
array_size(p);
```

And it will fail to compile for a case I'ld want it to compile for:

```
long x[1]; // assuming a platform with sizeof(long)==sizeof(void*)
array_size(x);
```

BTW, if you are declaring this function as a macro (and in C++ I'ld really prefer the template style solution), you should change all `array` in the macro to `(array)`.